# Selecting several lines in Intellij using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I select several lines in Intellij using keyboard shortcuts?
I found out that I can do it with

> ctrl + shift + right/left

But I have to press this buttons several times to select whole line.
What is more the selection starts from current caret position, so if it's not the beginning/end (depending of using left or right arrow) of the line, the whole first line is not selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I usually do is to hit the `Home` key, and then either:

1. `Shift+End` to select until the end of the current line, or
2. `Shift+Down` to select until the next line, and then keep pressing `Shift+Down` to select multiple lines.

Also, IntelliJ IDEA supports the "Extend Selection" and "Shrink Selection" commands, for which the default key bindings are `Ctrl+Alt+Left` and `Ctrl+Alt+Right`.

These allow you to select entire blocks of code rather than word by word.  You may still need to press the keys multiple times, but way fewer times than when selecting on a word by word basis.

Comment: Your way of doing this is nice. Thanks. But if it comes to  "Extend Selection" it's not the solution in this case, when for example I don't want to select all lines in entire block of code, but only some of them.